Help to identify this diode marked 'R4 08 E'
I am trying to repair wiper motor made by Bosch and need to identify the diode marked 'R4 08 E' for replacement. This is one of the few components that needs replacement in order for the circuit board to function properly. If anyone can help me find this, it is appreciated.


It's a Fagor FS1G rectifier. On the bottom right is the Fagor logo.



if it is a rectifier diode then there should be 4 diodes of the same type. Also looking at the year code, it says 'E' and not digits.

@JadonJung Why must there always be 4? You can use these diodes outside of a bridge rectifier. There also might be more diodes on the other side of the board. Year codes aren't necessarily numbers. Especially if only one character is used.
